# URLField appending to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a `ULRField` that I'm trying to link using `href` but when I click it I am takn to something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.example.com` rather than `www.example.com`

**models.py**

```
class Website(models.Model):
    website = models.URLField(max_length=100)
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="{{ dealer.website }}">{{ dealer.website }}</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the value with the `https://` protocol?

Comment: @schillingt that seems to work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer:

> Save the value with the `https://` protocol.